# Server cannot respond to more requests for same session

Tags: spring-boot, server-sent-events, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have the event stream code block below:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/stream/{columnId}/data", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Flux<Activity> streamingData(@PathVariable String columnId, HttpSession httpSession) {
        try {
            ColumnObject columnObject = streamHelper.findColumnObjectInListById(columnId);
            return streamHelper.getStreamData(httpSession.getId(), columnObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

After creating 6 columns through the endpoint, spring server will put all subsequent requests in the pending state.

( get, post methods for example)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/session/metrics", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> keepSessionAliveMetrics(HttpSession httpSession) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK); // STATE ONLY PENDING 
    }
```

[image]

Comment: This is a hard browser limit. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser. Spring isn't doing anything here, it is your browser.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I understand. How can you suggest a solution, my friend @M.Deinum

Comment: Fix your software/find a different way. The browser simply cannot handle more requests (and it even differs per browser).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Marten Deinum, this is a typical hard limit: browsers tend to limit the number of concurrent connections to a given domain.

If your application requires a lot of multiplexing, maybe using WebSockets is a better option as many message channels are established on a single TCP connection.

Comment: I think you're right. I already used WebSocket before event stream. But once you start using the Reactor API, the event stream makes more sense. Event stream can be managed more easily than websocket. You can see the example of the above controller code. As a result I could not imagine that such a problem would arise.

Comment: Spring WebFlux is considering alternate transports as well, see https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16751

Answer (score 0):

To bypass this limitation of the browsers, you can use Server-Sent Events over HTTP/2: HTTP/2 provides a multiplexing feature that enables to circumvent this HTTP/1 issue.
There is an excellent article about that: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/02/sse-websockets-data-flow-http2/

SpringBoot has an HTTP/2 support but may be not Spring WebFlux (with Netty, at least, at the time of writing): https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-http2

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking for what you're talking about. I think the only solution is to solve the software.

Answer (score 0):

Using SSE over HTTP/2 is certainly the best way to overcome the limitations your are experiencing. You can find more detailed information here: https://www.infoq.com/articles/websocket-and-http2-coexist